# Manage entangle from bash

Tags: tethering

I want to connect a Nikon camera to a Raspberry Pi with entangle installed.

From a remote computer, via wifi and ssh I have access to the RPi.

How can I simply take a photo (and optionally download it to the RPi) from command line?

I only see graphic interface to manage the camera.

Comment: Exactly *which* Nikon camera you intend to use may also be very applicable to your problem. The Nikon D3x000 and D5x00 series don't do many types of tethering particularly well.

Comment: I first tried my D600 with USB cable connected to Ubuntu and it worked okay.  I also tried an old Coolpix 8800 but it was not detected

Comment: But D600 is not detected by RPi (its SD card)

Comment: I'm not sure what the appropriate Stack Exchange site would be for working that out (SuperUser?), but the output of `lsusb`, `gphoto2 --auto-detect`, `ptpcam --list-devices` would be useful to figure it out.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's right. Both cards are listed in Nautilus (file browser in Ubuntu) but executing gphoto2 -> Error 'Could not claim the USB device'.  This is a question, how you say, for SuperUser.  BTW, gphoto2 autodetect does detect Nikon DSC D600.

Comment: Both cards? Sounds like you have some other software running which uses fuse to implement a filesystem over PTP. Identify and disable/reconfigure that and you'll probably find that gphoto2 works.

Comment: D600 has two SD slots. I use one for RAW and the other for JPEG backup.  Both are listed. I've read that gphoto2 cannot claim USB device because kernel is doing so. Seems it's not that simple to kernel unclaim

Comment: I also have to point out that graphic interface of Entangle works okay in Ubuntu, I am able to take and view photos I take from the program. Seems like Entangle sorts out the claim issue.

Comment: I realized how to fix that: unmount SD cards.  `gphoto2 --capture-image` -> New file is in location /capt0000.jpg on the camera                         
New file is in location /capt0000.nef on the camera    
No photos 'on the camera' not even hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [Entangle's `man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/entangle.1.html), it doesn't appear there are any command line options to control the camera and/or capture images.

Note that the bottom of Entangle's `man` page suggests to see also [`gphoto2`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gphoto2.1.html), which is a fairly full-featured command line interface to interact with and control the camera. `gphoto2`'s `man` page gives the following example usage:

> **`gphoto2 --capture-image --interval`** 60 **`--hook-script`**
>          `/usr/share/doc/gphoto2/test-hook.sh`
>
> ```
>     Capture one image every 60 seconds from now to eternity. The
>     example hook script will be called after each captured image has
>     been stored on the computer.
> ```

Comment: In further evidence, the home page of the [website](https://entangle-photo.org/) says "*It is built on top of libgphoto using GTK-3 for its interface*".

Comment: Despite I cannot check gphoto2 with my D600 (it is not detected by RPi) I marked the answer as a solution because it is the way to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Most graphical tethering programs for Linux are GUI wrappers around libgphoto2. The standard command-line interface for libgphoto2 is gphoto2.

The main competitor which I know of is libptp / ptpcam. I have a fork which compiles on my Raspberry Pi and adds an exposure bracketing feature at https://github.com/pjt33/ptpcam-fork